# TypeError: this.props.getRecipes is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I created an action that is basically a 'GET' fetch request and when the application compiles I get this `TypeError: this.props.getRecipes is not a function` error. What I am trying to to accomplish is when I create recipe in a form, it sends it to the backend to persist in the database, then the `getRecipes()` function will automatically perform a get fetch request that will update the displayed list on the frontend dynamically as recipes keep getting added.

I added an action called `getRecipes()`:

```
import Recipe from '../components/Recipe.js'

export const getRecipes = () => {
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:10524`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`


    return()=>{
        fetch(RECIPES_URL)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(recipes => recipes.map(recipe => {
          return <div><Recipe recipe={recipe} key={recipe.id}/></div>
        }));
    }
}
```

And I'm importing in my `RecipeList` component and using a Lifecyle method which is pretty standard if it involves a `fetch` or `async` request.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import { getRecipes } from '../actions/getRecipes.js'


class RecipeList extends Component {
  
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getRecipes()<------- it's saying that this is the issue here
  }

render() {
    
   return (
    <div>
     {getRecipes}
    </div>
   )
    
  }




 }

export default RecipeList;
```

And then it should display here on my RecipesContainer component.

```
import RecipeInput from '../components/RecipeInput'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { postRecipes } from '../actions/postRecipes.js'
import { getRecipes } from '../actions/getRecipes'


class RecipeContainer extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
               <RecipeInput addRecipe={this.props.addRecipe} /> 
               <RecipeList recipes={this.props.recipes} deleteRecipe={this.props.deleteRecipe} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    

}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        recipes: state.recipes
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return{
    postRecipes: () => dispatch(postRecipes()),
    getRecipes: () => dispatch(getRecipes())//I don't think this is needed if I am not calling a dispatch on this
    
    }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(RecipeContainer)
```

Where am I going wrong that's producing this error when the app compiles?

Comment: Why did you think that *would* be in the props? You connect the container, but then don't pass it through when rendering and instead import it directly; that doesn't make sense. And don't you want to do something with the value it resolves to?

Comment: Honestly I was referencing to some other examples on how to do a fetch request (Thunk), and from the way I put it together, I thought I was passing in props, but I forget that I am not passing in anything, but just retrieving.  I hope this makes sense.....???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getRecipes()<------- it's saying that this is the issue here
  }
```

To:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    getRecipes();
  }
```

Comment: I did, but I have wait I believe another 10 mins before it lets me. I have been seeing this lately on here after I post something.